# Unable to get the value of a variable inside Rails erb tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I want to understand the erb usage. In the below code I am unable to figure out how to get the value of (group.id) in the if clause using the erb tags.

This probably has a very basic solution but I am unable to get proper answers.

The below code gives me syntax error.

```
<% current_user.favorite_groups.to_a.each do |group| %>
    <%= if (group.id).newfavorite_texts.exists?(id: text.id) %>
      <%= group.name %>
      <%= link_to # do something %>
    <% else %>
      <%= group.name %>
      <%= link_to # do something else %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `<% if group.newfavorite_texts.exists?(id: text.id) %>`

Comment: @Pavan Thanks a lot this worked.

Comment: Great! I've added it as an answer. Accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be get going with the below code

```
<% current_user.favorite_groups.to_a.each do |group| %>
  <% if group.newfavorite_texts.exists?(id: text.id) %>
    <%= group.name %>
    <%= link_to # do something %>
  <% else %>
    <%= group.name %>
    <%= link_to # do something else %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```